# Is there a way to Hide/unhide all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have the following HTML and I want to hide all the children of the 'overlay' div dynamically

```html
<div id="overlay" class="foo">
    <h2 class="title">title</h2>
    <h1 id="bar">sub-title</h1>
    <button id="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```

is there a better way to mass hide/unhide these elements than calling .className = 'hide' on them individually?

*note that I want to retrieve those later so looping over them with .remove() or setting div innerHTML to an empty string is not an option

Comment: You may have a look for css visibility property

Comment: Why don't you just hide the `overlay` element?

Comment: @Evren Presumably he's using a property like that in the `.hide` CSS

Comment: Hide a parent and all it's children are hidden. So if you don't want the id=overlay hidden use an inner parent for all the other children and just toggle one parent

Comment: @barmar it just hides the element's css properties but not the children element

Comment: @Barmar you are right i did not pay attention for his code

Comment: What do you mean by "hides the element's css properties"? You don't hide properties, you hide elements. And as pointed out, hiding a container hides all its contents.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jy9254bn/

Comment: @Evren Also, usually `display: none;` is preferable to `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @barmar I meant that if the div has background color it hid the color and box style but not the children elements

Comment: @barmar Thank you! your approach works. I have posted the solution you suggested. I was previously trying to hide with .hide class only which did not work for me

Comment: if you hide the parent their sons also disappear,

Comment: But what about the problem of not seeing the background of the DIV?

Answer (score 2):

In your css you can create this:

```
#overlay.hidden-content > * {
 visibility: hidden
}
```

And add `hidden-content` to your div with `overlay` id to hide all the child elements.